# How do I update a flag on a array of Photo objects that I favorited a particular photo?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a simple photo categories array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    category: 1001,
    photos: [
      { id: 100101, url: 'url.com/100101', favorite: false},
      { id: 100102, url: 'url.com/100102', favorite: false}
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 1002,
    photos: [
      { id: 100201, url: 'url.com/100201', favorite: false},
      { id: 100202, url: 'url.com/100202', favorite: false}
    ]
  }
]
```

If I favorite photoId 100201, how can I update my array so that 100201 is updated to `favorite: true`?   I am trying to look at lodash documentation but I am not sure what I should be looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/215552) answer yours?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that this array is stored in a variable named `categories`, and assuming (based on the data you provided) that each photo id starts with the exact category id, then:

```
function inCategory(category: string, id: string): boolean {
    return id.substring(0, category.length) === category;
}

function favorite(photoId: number): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        if (inCategory(categories[i].category.toString(), photoId.toString())) {
            for (let j = 0; j < categories[i].photos.length; j++) {
                if (categories[i].photos[j].id === photoId) {
                    categories[i].photos[j].favorite = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20categories%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%201001%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20photos%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20100101%2C%20url%3A%20'url.com%2F100101'%2C%20favorite%3A%20false%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20100102%2C%20url%3A%20'url.com%2F100102'%2C%20favorite%3A%20false%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20category%3A%201002%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20photos%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20100201%2C%20url%3A%20'url.com%2F100201'%2C%20favorite%3A%20false%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%20100202%2C%20url%3A%20'url.com%2F100202'%2C%20favorite%3A%20false%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20inCategory(category%3A%20string%2C%20id%3A%20string)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20id.substring(0%2C%20category.length)%20%3D%3D%3D%20category%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20favorite(photoId%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%09for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20categories.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09if%20(inCategory(categories%5Bi%5D.category.toString()%2C%20photoId.toString()))%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09for%20(let%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%20categories%5Bi%5D.photos.length%3B%20j%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09if%20(categories%5Bi%5D.photos%5Bj%5D.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20photoId)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09categories%5Bi%5D.photos%5Bj%5D.favorite%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: This makes an assumption about the format of category and photo ids that should probably be pointed out in the answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You're absolutely right! And I honestly meant to, but then forgot. Updated, thanks!